# How correctly to link program against library

Tags: shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, ldd

I run `./myprogram` and it gives me a warning:

```
Warning: Your program was compiled with SimGrid version 3.13.90, and then linked against SimGrid 3.13.0. Proceeding anyway.
```

Try`ldd myprogram` and it gives following:

```
libsimgrid.so.3.13.90 => /usr/lib/libsimgrid.so.3.13.90 (0x00007f338ef47000)
```

Then I go to `usr/lib` and type `ll *sim*` in terminal:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ken ken       21 июл 28 19:29 libsimgrid.so -> libsimgrid.so.3.13.90*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ken ken 12307480 июл 28 19:29 libsimgrid.so.3.13.90*
```

In `CMakeLists.txt` I link library `simgrid` in such way:

```
target_link_libraries(CSim2Sim simgrid)
```

Why `myprogram` still links against `SimGrid 3.13.0` (it doesn't exist in `/usr/lib` while `SimGrid 3.13.90` does)?

**UPDATE**:

Command `locate libsimgrid.so` in ternimal gives:

```
/home/ken/Downloads/simgrid-master/lib/libsimgrid.so
/home/ken/Downloads/simgrid-master/lib/libsimgrid.so.3.13.90
/home/ken/SimGrid/lib/libsimgrid.so
/home/ken/SimGrid/lib/libsimgrid.so.3.13.90
/usr/lib/libsimgrid.so
/usr/lib/libsimgrid.so.3.13.90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message seems buggy, it looks like your application was actually compiled with 3.13.0, and linked to libsimgrid 3.13.90. The order was inverted in the message, I will fix that.

It could be a problem with your includes when you compile your code, I think. Please check that you don't use old versions of msg.h/simgrid_config.h files when you compile your app (maybe there are still one in /usr/include ?).

To check, you can look for SIMGRID_VERSION_PATCH in simgrid_config.h. it should be 90 in a recent one, not 0.